# Lock on lid close

Tags: 22.04

I did `vim /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and set `HandleLidSwitch=lock`, but still, when I close my lid, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you use systemctl restart systemd-logind command?
This will save the file and restart the service to apply the changes.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the system as well.

Comment: 1) if your ACPI doesn't work, you will not get notified when the lid closes. Have you any indication that your "close lid" event is triggered? 2) Usually a display manager handles the locking. Did you set there anything?  3)Do you have an NVIDIA GPU ? Could you answer those 3 questions in your question?

Comment: It worked in all other previous versions. I don't have NVIDIA gpu. Where is display manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: Restart the system logind:

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind`

After that verify: Replace the SESSION_ID with your user session:

`sudo loginctl show-session SESSION_ID -p HandleLidSwitch`

Then relog and use:

`journalctl -xe`
Using the jurnalctl -xe will show you the errors. Ctrl+C to exit.
I hope it work.